# How to transform a JavaScript Date to a different timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, timestamp

If I run `var myDate = new Date('29-06-2016 10:00')`, `myDate` will only contain one thing: a number. The number of milliseconds from 01-01-1970 00:00:00 GMT to 29-06-2016 10:00:00 XXX

XXX being the timezone of the OS. In my case `BST` (because it is a summer date, in winter would be GMT).

Now... What if I want the milliseconds from 01-01-1970... to 29-06-2016 10:00:00 GMT-7?

I only found methods to tell me what time is in the GMT-7 timezone when in BST timezone is 29-06-2016 10:00:00, but that is not what I am looking for!

Also, to change an environmental variable so the timezone is GMT-7 is not an option.

Comment: Maybe moment can help.. but not sure. http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way of doing it, using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) as [ErikS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098201/how-to-transform-a-javascript-date-to-a-different-timezone/#comment63630834_38098201) suggested:

```
// This code is running in a Node.js server configured to use UTC

// Incorrect date, as it is interpret as UTC.
// However, we do this to get the utcOffset
var auxDate = moment.tz(new Date('2016-6-23 10:15:0'), 'US/Mountain');

// Get the milliseconds since 1970 of the date as if it were interpreted 
// as GMT-7 or GMT-6 (depends on the date because of Daylight Saving Time)
var milliseconds = auxDate.valueOf() - auxDate.utcOffset() * 60000;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the date string in the following format

```
"2016-06-29T10:00:00-07:00"
```

That lets you set the timezone relative GMT (not 100% sure on the timezone, but it's client side so does depend on their locale).

I had a similar thing where JS was changing the time on date objects and the only way I found was to set up the date and set this.

Bonus info, to get this from a .NET DateTime using the following string format.

```
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"
```

Comment: yup, `Date.parse("2016-06-29T10:00:00-07:00")` works in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge so looks like a safe bet.

Comment: In my case does not work. I am working with a server that is (and must be) in UTC... so I would need to know when is summer time and winter time and change the string dates consequently.